# How to call axios/api call in Nativescript application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to build a small application on `Nativescript-vue` where I'm having backend `laravel` framework for api calls which needs to be called to get relevant data. For example if user wants to login he needs to validate its credentials through api `oauth/token` so I'm trying to call this through `axios` here is my code:

My `settings.js` file contains.

```
export const authHeader = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

this is being imported inside my axios calls:

```
const postData = {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: user.email,
    password: user.password,
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    scope: '',
    provider: provider
}
const authUser = {}
axios.post(authUrl, postData, {headers: authHeader}).then(response => {
    console.log('Inside oauth/token url')
    if(response.status === 200)
    {
        console.log('response received')
    }
})
.catch((err) => {
    if(err.response.status === 401){
       reject('Validation error')
    }
    else
       reject('Something went wrong')
})
```

when I try to build with command `tns debug android --bundle` I get `chrome-devtools` which shows me:

[image: api being called]

Digging more deep into it I can see headers are being passed but those are only provisional:

[image: headers]

As you can see I've `console.log` inside my application which show me:

[image: console.log]

Even while compiling I get following errors:

[image: compiling error]

Guide me how can I achieve this. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Similarly I used `nativescript's` own `http` [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http) something like this:

```
const httpModule = require("http");

httpModule.request({
    url: "http://iguru.local/oauth/token",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    content: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: this.user.email,
        password: this.user.password,
        client_id: 'check',
        client_secret: 'check',
        scope: '',
        provider: 'check'
    })
}).then((response) => {
    // Argument (response) is HttpResponse
    console.log('Action called')
    if(response.status === 200)
    {
        console.log('Response recieved')
    }
}, (e) => {
    console.log('Something went wrong')
});
```

I'm getting the same result, moreover I tried api from server end ex http://confidenceeducare.com/oauth/token it happens to be same. Normal `Vue` application calls the api perfectly fine. I guess there is some problem with the `nativescript` application. Do I need to import something more? I'm stuck with it.

If anybody is thinking my api end point is broken, I tried using the urls mentioned in example i.e. `https://httpbin.org/post`:

[image: http]

and:

[image]

When I checked my api in `postman` it is working over there, I'm getting at least a response with status code:

[image: postman response]

**Edit 2:**
For reference github repository https://github.com/nitish1986/sample_mobile_app

Comment: Based on most of what you printed, and looking really quickly at Axios; it won't work on NativeScript -- it is designed for Node.   Anything that pulls node specific libraries doesn't work on NativeScript.     Now as to your edit; that code should actually work; what error are you seeing from using the nativescript http code?

Comment: @Nathanael I'm not getting any errors, it is just waiting for response, even in command prompt it just wait for the response and I don't know why this is showing as document in chrome console in-spite of being a XHR request.

Comment: Whatever you posted should actually work. This may be helpful https://www.nativescript.org/blog/make-http-requests-to-remote-web-services-in-a-nativescript-vue-app

Comment: @NarendraMongiya That is what it is bothering me more, wherever I've researched it says your code is fine and it should work.

Comment: is it possible for you create playground?

Comment: or a github may be?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya You can find it here! https://github.com/nitish1986/sample_mobile_app

Comment: @NitishKumar Assuming this backend is running locally, are you sure that the device you are testing on can actually reach it?

Comment: @NitishKumar Are you sure you're using Axios correctly? I usually have to pass some `{ withCredentials: true }` kind of option to make it work with authentication? And you probably don't need your object `authHeader`

Comment: @Dexter Yes it is working fine that is why I've shared https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPJhf.png this last image

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 Yes, I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested the exact same project you have shared in Github with Android 8.0, it works perfectly fine. The axios call hits the error block as the response status (`error.response.status`) is 401 and data (`error.response.data`) returns the exact same response you see from Postman.

If you are using Android 9 or later it might fail as you haven't enabled `useCleartextTraffic` on your `application` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application 
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
```

With iOS also it would fail as you haven't enabled app transport security. Just to allow all Http communication within your app, you have to add the following key to your `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

In case if you want to allow only specific domains, then use `NSExceptionDomains` key and list the endpoints.

Comment: I think there must be some more configuration in AndroidManifest.xml but still you gave me an idea about it. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with how axios is imported. Try:

```js
import axios from 'axios/dist/axios'
```

this also solves the `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in...` error.

When importing the package normally my requests failed, returning the error

```
Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code null"
```